# ERROR TypeError: "_co.bankId is undefined" (Angular 7)

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular7, angular-formbuilder, angular-material-7

I have a subproject in my angular app. In this subproject I want to create a form with input fields. These fields need a validation and need to show an error optionally, if the field is invalid (e.g. required). Well, the problem is, the "formControlName" property is undefined (look at the title of this thread).

The code is defined as follows:

```
// Component file:
...
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
...

export class ConfigFormComponent implements OnInit {
  orderReport: FormGroup;

  createForm() {
    return this.fb.group({
      bankId: ['', Validators.required],
      ...
    });
  }

  constructor(private fb: FormBuilder) { 
    this.orderReport = this.createForm();
  }
}
```

and the HTML:

```
 // View file:
    ...
    <mat-card>
       <form [formGroup]="orderReport">
          <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
             <mat-label>Bank ID</mat-label>
             <input matInput placeholder="Bank ID" formControlName="bankId" required>
             <mat-error *ngIf="bankId.invalid">The field shows an error.</mat-error>
          </mat-form-field>
          ...
       </form>
    </mat-card>
```

I also added the `FormsModule` and `ReactiveFormsModule` to the AppModule file. Have anyone an idea?

I'm using Angular 7.3.2 with Angular Material 7.3.2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To access the validation status of a form control, you need to get a reference to that form control, in your case using: `orderReport.get('bankId')`, then you can access `invalid`.

Your HTML code should be:

```
<mat-error *ngIf="orderReport.get('bankId').invalid">The field shows an error.</mat-error>
```

Comment: Did they forget to update the docs at the angular sites? Nothing is described there? It works thanks. Is it better to define the get method in the component class?

Comment: Do you have a link to the part of the docs you mentioned? Don't define it in you component, because it will pollute it. It is not necessary to define it in your component.

Comment: https://angular.io/guide/reactive-forms They don't use the get()-method. Also in the angular material docs => https://material.angular.io/components/form-field/overview#error-messages

Comment: Please look carefully at the code examples they have on their page. They always use `[formControl]` instead of `formControlName`. If you use `formControl` you have direct access to the status because **it is** the form control. If you use `formControlName`, you first have to get the `formControl` to access the status.

Comment: Could you please show me the part where they describe when I need to use the get()-method? Thanks :)